# Grouping by resetting cumulative sum

Tags: numba, python-polars

I have several files in a dataframe with their file_size. I want to group the files in groups under a `file_size_threshold` (in my example, the file_size_threshold is 3).
As an example of the expected behavour: this is my input dataframe:

```py
import polars as pl

data = {
    "bucket": ["bucket1"] * 8,
    "full_path": ["file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt","file5.txt","file6.txt","file7.txt","file8.txt"],
    "ETag": ["11c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f","21c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172g","31c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f","41c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f","51c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f","61c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f","71c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f","81c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f"],
    "file_size": [1, 2, 2,2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
}
print(pl.DataFrame(data))
#shape: (8, 4)
#┌─────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
#│ bucket  ┆ full_path ┆ ETag                            ┆ file_size │
#│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---                             ┆ ---       │
#│ str     ┆ str       ┆ str                             ┆ i64       │
#╞═════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╡
#│ bucket1 ┆ file1.txt ┆ 11c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file2.txt ┆ 21c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172g ┆ 2         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file3.txt ┆ 31c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file4.txt ┆ 41c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file5.txt ┆ 51c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file6.txt ┆ 61c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 3         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file7.txt ┆ 71c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         │
#│ bucket1 ┆ file8.txt ┆ 81c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         │
#└─────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

And this is expected result (for this particular case, where `file_size_threshold=3`) :

```py
shape: (8, 5)
┌─────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
│ bucket  ┆ full_path ┆ ETag                            ┆ file_size ┆ group_number │
│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---                             ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ str       ┆ str                             ┆ i64       ┆ i64          │
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ bucket1 ┆ file1.txt ┆ 11c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         ┆ 1            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file2.txt ┆ 21c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172g ┆ 2         ┆ 1            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file3.txt ┆ 31c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         ┆ 2            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file4.txt ┆ 41c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         ┆ 3            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file5.txt ┆ 51c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         ┆ 3            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file6.txt ┆ 61c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 3         ┆ 4            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file7.txt ┆ 71c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         ┆ 5            │
│ bucket1 ┆ file8.txt ┆ 81c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         ┆ 5            │
└─────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┘
```

So, file1 and 2 are group number 1, file3 is group number 2, file4 and 5 is group number 3, file6 is group number 4 and file 7 and 8 is group number 5.

> **Clarification note**: `file2` and `file3` are in a different group as `file_size_threshold=3`. File size of `file1` is 1 so it is part of the 1st group. Second row cum file_size is `1+2=3`, minor or equal than threshold then in the same group.
> When it comes to `file3`, you will have `1+2+2`, that is bigger than 3 therefore `file2` and `file3` needs to be in an different group.

Any idea how to solve it using Polars?

I tried to use `cum_sum()` function and `mod()`, but I could not find a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this works with `cum_sum` and `mod` or `floordiv` because there's not an obvious way to make it restart when you create a new group.

One way to overcome this is to make a compiled ufunc with [numba's `guvectorize`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) decorator.

```
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64, nb.int64[:])], '(n),()->(n)', nopython=True)
def make_groups(file_sizes, threshold, results):
    cur_group_id = 1
    cur_group_size = 0
    for i in range(file_sizes.shape[0]):
        cur_group_size+=file_sizes[i]
        if cur_group_size > threshold:
            cur_group_size = file_sizes[i]
            cur_group_id+=1
        results[i]=cur_group_id
```

then it's just

```
df.with_columns(group=make_groups(pl.col('file_size'),3))
shape: (8, 5)
┌─────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ bucket  ┆ full_path ┆ ETag                            ┆ file_size ┆ group │
│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---                             ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ str       ┆ str                             ┆ i64       ┆ i64   │
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ bucket1 ┆ file1.txt ┆ 11c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         ┆ 1     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file2.txt ┆ 21c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172g ┆ 2         ┆ 1     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file3.txt ┆ 31c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         ┆ 2     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file4.txt ┆ 41c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         ┆ 3     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file5.txt ┆ 51c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         ┆ 3     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file6.txt ┆ 61c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 3         ┆ 4     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file7.txt ┆ 71c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 1         ┆ 5     │
│ bucket1 ┆ file8.txt ┆ 81c9d17dc657860c447e655fa79172f ┆ 2         ┆ 5     │
└─────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

You can make an expression wrapper and [register a namespace](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_expr_namespace.html) but I like monkey patching it to `pl.Expr` so you can call it from the column

```
pl.Expr.make_groups = lambda self, threshold: (
    make_groups(self, threshold)
)

##now you can do
df.with_columns(group=pl.col('file_size').make_groups(3))
```

Comment: Completely agree with you there's not obvious way to restart when you create a new group.
Yes, definitely I like your approach to be able to use the p.Expr syntax :)

I would be good in the future that Polars support that with some Polars Expression, but I am really happy with your solution.
It works well, and it executes fast enough :)

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score -1):

Would it work to use cum_sum, then divide by 3, then use pl.floor + 1?

Comment: That is not working. If you try it you will see that file1.txt and file2.txt are part of a different group (when should be part of the same group)

Comment: Do it with pl.ceil and it should