# High efficiency computation to get bounded cum_sum

Tags: python-polars

I'm looking for assistance to get a pl.Serie that has the amount of ball in a box in high computational efficiency

I've a request to add or remove a ball in a box but the box cannot have more than a max quantity, so I need to know how many balls are in a box

```
max_qty_allowed = 3
requests        = [ 0,0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1]

ball_qty        = [ 0,0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  2,  1, 1, 1,  0,  0, 0,  0]
delta_ball      = [ 0,0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1,  0, 0,  0]
```

I tried with a custom func but is too slow:

```
def get_ball_in_then_box(*,
                         requests: pl.Series,
                         max_val=3,
                         min_val=0,
                         ) -> pl.Series:
    """    
    Series: '' [i32]
      [input]   [oper]  [output]
         0        0         0
        +1       +1         1
        +1       +1         2
        +1        0         2    
        +1        0         2    
        -1       -1         1
        +1       +1         2
        -1       -1         1
        -1       -1         0
        -1        0         0    


    :param max_val: max allowed in the box
    :param min_val: min allowed in the box = 0
    :return: balls in the box
    """
    
    balls_in_the_box = 0
    balls_in_the_box_list = []
    
    for request in requests:
        if request > 0:
            if balls_in_the_box < max_val:
                if balls_in_the_box + request <= max_val:
                    balls_in_the_box += request
                else:
                    balls_in_the_box = max_val
        elif request < 0:
            if balls_in_the_box > min_val:
                if balls_in_the_box + request >= min_val:
                    balls_in_the_box += request
                else:
                    balls_in_the_box = min_val
        
        balls_in_the_box_list.append(balls_in_the_box)
    
    return pl.Series(values=balls_in_the_box_list)
```

Dataframe is 10mln rows

Comment: Polars doesn't really offer a way to speed up this kind of algorithm. You can write a plugin in Rust but using Numba is easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77660252/

Answer (score 3):

This is almost the same as the linked question except this one is even simpler, it just needs `min` and `max` with no if statements.

The function is:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64, nb.int64, nb.int64[:])], '(n),(),()->(n)', nopython=True)
def cum_in_box(requests, max_val, min_val, results):
    results[0] = max(min_val,min(max_val,requests[0]))
    for i in range(1, requests.shape[0]):
        results[i]=max(min_val,min(max_val,requests[i]+results[i-1]))
```

then you use it as

```
df.with_columns(
    balls_in_box=cum_in_box(pl.col('requests'), 3,0)
)
```

With a 10M row df it takes 0.1s.