# Python Polars optimization in a iterative loop

Tags: python-polars

Trying to port pandas code to polars for learning purposes, hit a strange issue.

The pandas code executes faster than polars code. Not sure I am implementing in polars the right way and need some guidance.

**Pseudo Pandas Code**

```
df['a'] = 0.00
df['b'] = 0.00
for i in range(x, y):
    df['a'].iat[i] = df['c'].iat[i] \
                        if df['c'].iat[i] < df['a'].iat[i - 1] or df['d'].iat[i - 1] > df['a'].iat[i - 1] \
                        else df['a'].iat[i - 1]
    df['b'].iat[i] = df['e'].iat[i] \
                        if df['e'].iat[i] > df['b'].iat[i - 1] or df['d'].iat[i - 1] < df['b'].iat[i - 1] \
                        else df['b'].iat[i - 1]
```

**Equivalent Pseudo Polars Code**

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(0.00).alias('a'))
df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(0.00).alias('b'))

for i in range(x, y):
    df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.first().cum_count()==i)
                            .then(pl.when(
                                (pl.col('c') < pl.col('a').shift(1))
                                .or_(pl.col('d').shift(1) > pl.col('a').shift(1)))
                                .then('c')
                                .otherwise(pl.col('a').shift(1)))
                            .otherwise('a')
                            .alias('a'))
    df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.first().cum_count()==i)
                            .then(pl.when(
                                (pl.col('e') > pl.col('b').shift(1))
                                .or_(pl.col('d').shift(1) < pl.col('b').shift(1)))
                                .then('e')
                                .otherwise(pl.col('b').shift(1)))
                            .otherwise('b')
                            .alias('b'))
```

Any guidance would be really helpful

**Update**: As requested adding a reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import polars as pl

def pandas_code(df, x, y):
    df['a'] = 0.00
    df['b'] = 0.00
    for i in range(x, y):
        df['a'].iat[i] = df['c'].iat[i] \
                            if df['c'].iat[i] < df['a'].iat[i - 1] or df['d'].iat[i - 1] > df['a'].iat[i - 1] \
                            else df['a'].iat[i - 1]
        df['b'].iat[i] = df['e'].iat[i] \
                            if df['e'].iat[i] > df['b'].iat[i - 1] or df['d'].iat[i - 1] < df['b'].iat[i - 1] \
                            else df['b'].iat[i - 1]
    
    return df

def polars_code(df, x, y):
    df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(0.00).alias('a'))
    df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(0.00).alias('b'))

    for i in range(x, y):
        df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.first().cum_count()==i)
                                .then(pl.when(
                                    (pl.col('c') < pl.col('a').shift(1))
                                    .or_(pl.col('d').shift(1) > pl.col('a').shift(1)))
                                    .then('c')
                                    .otherwise(pl.col('a').shift(1)))
                                .otherwise('a')
                                .alias('a'))
        df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.first().cum_count()==i)
                                .then(pl.when(
                                    (pl.col('e') > pl.col('b').shift(1))
                                    .or_(pl.col('d').shift(1) < pl.col('b').shift(1)))
                                    .then('e')
                                    .otherwise(pl.col('b').shift(1)))
                                .otherwise('b')
                                .alias('b'))    


range_start = 2
range_end = 1000 
original_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    c=np.random.randint(300, 700, size=range_end),
    d=np.random.randint(300, 700, size=range_end),
    e=np.random.randint(300, 700, size=range_end)
))

start_time = time.time()
df = pandas_code(original_df, range_start,range_end)
end_time = time.time()

print("Pandas took -> "+ str(end_time - start_time))

# Import the above pandas original_df to polars
polars_df = pl.from_pandas(original_df, include_index=True)


start_time = time.time()
polars_df = polars_code(polars_df, range_start,range_end)
end_time = time.time()

print("Polars took -> "+ str(end_time - start_time))
```

The more the value of `range_end` is, the more time `polars` takes to compute.

Comment: can you make a reproducible example

Comment: @ignoring_gravity added the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of task is just not something you would use the Polars Expression API for.

Pandas took -> `4.421391010284424`

It is possible to write it using the same approach as your pandas example:

```py
def polars_code_2(df, x, y):
    df = df.with_columns(a = pl.lit(0.00))
    df = df.with_columns(b = pl.lit(0.00))

    for i in range(x, y):
        a, b, d = df['a'][i - 1], df['b'][i - 1], df['d'][i - 1]
        c, e = df['c'][i], df['e'][i]
        
        df[i, 'a'] = c if c < a or d > a else a
        df[i, 'b'] = e if e > b or d < b else b
        
    return df
```

Polars #2 took -> `2.261274814605713`

However, all that's really being timed here is DataFrame overhead (and we're not really "using Polars").

```py
def lists_code(df, x, y):
    A = [0.00] * len(df)
    B = [0.00] * len(df)
    C = list(df['c'])
    D = list(df['d'])
    E = list(df['e'])
    
    for i in range(x, y):
        A[i] = C[i] if C[i] < A[i - 1] or D[i - 1] > A[i - 1] else A[i - 1]
        B[i] = E[i] if E[i] > B[i - 1] or D[i - 1] < B[i - 1] else B[i - 1]
        
    return A, B
```

Lists took -> `0.023373869705200195`

The general recommendation for speeding up these "running total" type tasks is to use numba:

- [High efficiency computation to get bounded cum_sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77757488)

Comment: Thanks for both the solutions. As you rightly pointed the lists solution makes sense here.