# Polars - inserting values by row based on conditions

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have 2 columns named 'lower' filled with decimals and 'triger' filled with 1s and 0 based on previous calculations.

Goal is to rewrite 'lower' column based on new condition.
I tried many diferent things, with 'with_columns', .apply lambdas, custom functions,...

if the value in current row 'lower' is lower than in previous row, than just overwrite it with the previous value. as long as 'triger' is above 0.

where i am right now is giving me ambiguous errors:

```
df.select([
        pl.col('lower').map(lambda x: x if ((pl.col('triger') > 0) & (pl.col('lower') < pl.col('lower'))) else pl.col('lower').shift(1))
    ])
```

i also tried this for instance:

```
df.with_columns([
        pl.when((pl.col('triger') > 0) & (pl.col('lower') < pl.col('lower_1')))
        .then(pl.col('lower').shift(periods=1))
        .otherwise(pl.col('lower')).alias('lower')
    ])
```

Problem is, the expression has to check the new (just calculated) value of 'lower' in the shift(1) when calculating new row.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Since im quite new to polars it might be a silly problem, but i havent been abele to find anything similar online

How code works is it has 3 columns of values. upperband, lowerband and tf_close. all are close to eachother, tf_close is mostly between them unless its not, thats what we are dealing with in the code. upperband and lowerband are just a calculated distance away from it, to their respective directions.
We make a new column 'triger' and set its value to 1 or -1 based on ifelse. Than we clamp the bands based on that so it cant be lower or higher then previous reading. than we take vales we are interested in from upper and lower band based on last elif.

python code example, it has some extra thing in it. Question is focused on the mid part of the code. If you have a beter solution or some guiadance to do it all in a few polars expressions that would be greately apreciated as well

```
triger_column, indicator_column = [1] * m, [0] * m  # make 2 empty arrays of size m
for i in range(ATR_lag, m):
    if pandas_df['tf_close'][i] > df_upperband[i - 1]:  # if close0 > upper-1 change triger to 1
        triger_column[i] = 1
    elif pandas_df['tf_close'][i] < df_lowerband[i - 1]:  # if close0 < lower-1 change triger to -1
        triger_column[i] = -1
    else:
        triger_column[i] = triger_column[i - 1]  # if none of the above, than keep previous triger (1 or -1)
        if triger_column[i] > 0 and df_lowerband.iloc[i] < df_lowerband.iloc[i - 1]:  # if 1, and lower band wants to go down, than keep the line where it was on previous candle
            df_lowerband.iloc[i] = df_lowerband.iloc[i - 1]
        if triger_column[i] < 0 and df_upperband.iloc[i] > df_upperband.iloc[i - 1]:  # if -1, and upper bands wants to go up, than keep the line where it was on previous candle
            df_upperband.iloc[i] = df_upperband.iloc[i - 1]
    if triger_column[i] > 0:
        indicator_column[i] = df_lowerband.iloc[i]
    else:
        indicator_column[i] = df_upperband.iloc[i]

df_super = pd.DataFrame({  # make a df from arrays
    "line": indicator_column,
    'Signal': triger_column,
}, index=pandas_df.index)
```

output would be something like this:

```
0.886724,-1
0.886724,-1
0.886724,-1
0.883666,1
0.884114,1
0.884603,1
0.885013,1
0.885361,1
0.885692,1
0.886326,1
0.886906,1
0.887325,1
0.887435,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.887588,1
0.890039,-1
0.890039,-1
0.890039,-1
```

Comment: Can you add a small sample dataframe (and perhaps the original pandas code?) so that we can see the expected output?

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I don't think there's any nice way to do this in "native" Polars: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808690 (It's essentially a vertical equivalent of [`pl.cumfold`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.cumfold.html#polars-cumfold)) which would be highly inefficient: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12165

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I also noticed on some reformatted code from pandas to polars that it runs slower, but not in all cases. So i will try the approach in the post you suggested and see. Thanks again @jqurious

Comment: You're on a really old version, I recommend upgrading to the newest version. It won't help in this specific problem but there are many other bugs and issues that are resolved in updated versions.

Comment: its on 20.2. not that old @DeanMacGregor but thanks. will check

Comment: You say you're on 20.2 but you're using `.map(...)` which has been deprecated since before 19 so I guess my other suggestion would be to update your code before they fully remove `map` rather than it just giving a warning.

Comment: Also, is `lower` actually `Decimal`s or just `Float`s? You didn't give an input example only output which is tough to do anything with.